# Is it a good idea to get fired?

Tags: termination

Hypothetically, is it ever a good idea to get fired?

Let's say I don't like my job and want to leave. I interview for some stuff and get offered a position elsewhere. Instead of giving notice at my job, it would be a lot quicker to just get fired and then I would leave with a severance.

I see no downside.

Anyone ever tried?
What obvious downside am I not seeing?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yh, I knew there would be a downside. If it's a really different industry then it might not matter is what I figure.

Comment: I don't get the down vote. What's that for? It's a reasonable question to me that is not elsewhere on this site. I checked.

Comment: If you are a professional then you should always behave in a professional manner.  Intentionally behaving in such a way that you would get fired is not in any way professional.  Unprofessional conduct always comes back to haunt you.

Comment: " and then I would leave with a severance." Can you add a location? Where do you get a severance when you are fired for cause?

Comment: Was this posted by George Costanza? You trying to get fired in a way that other people will remember what happened and think "Damn....now that guy got canned!"

Comment: In some cases, getting fired means you forfeit severance.

Comment: @stuartstevenson, If you get a new job and if both you and your manager don't like each other, then you can come up to him and tell him you just get a new job and want to leave, and ask him if  you can leave right away in the next 1 or 2 days ? Chances are good that he will say "YES".  No one has ever said that it is a good idea to get themselves fired.

Comment: How exactly to do plan to "get fired"? Why do you think that process will happen faster than a notice period? Where I am, it would surely not, unless the offense was actually injuring someone, say. Even then probably suspension while a prolonged process plays out.

Comment: If you didn't like it and have a position lined up elsewhere, who cares? Just quit and explain you got a better offer, and say no more. You should be happy.

Comment: The only ways I can think of that can get you fired faster than giving a notice period, is you do something illegal and/or very stupid. If it is for the sake of unemployment, doing something deliberately stupid can actually void your unemployment, as can illegal activities (fully justified termination). I see no positive from this at all.

Comment: are you using your real name as your user name on here ?

Comment: Not sure what country you are in.  Typically, in US. if you get fired you don't get severance or unemployment.  Still, it seems a bad idea to get fired anywhere.  If you signed a contract you are trying to get out of, I would consult a lawyer.

Comment: Can you get a job without references or lying about who your most recent employer was?

Answer (score 15):

First, if you're in a position where a termination may lead to a severance, then you're likely in an industry where people run into each other on a regular basis. Even in the largest cities various industries tend to have very specific networks. If you do something bad enough to get yourself fired in a shorter time than a notice period it will earn you a reputation in your industry.

Second, if you do something as described to get fired, it's almost certainly to be something for which severance would be denied outright.

Third, if you're in such a position you're likely accepting a position similar or better. It's entirely possible that you end up failing a reference check with your gaining company and/or your reputation catches up to you at the new company, and you don't survive the first 90 days which many companies consider a probationary period.

Hopefully you haven't used your real name in creating this account because you're effectively stating that you can't see the downside to an obviously unethical behavior. This should be concerning to anyone working with you or for whom you're working.

Comment: I'll also add that *depending on the jurisdiction* (don't know where OP is), getting fired for cause can make you ineligible for certain government benefits

Answer (score 2):

Getting fired is never a good idea

Also, to get fired quickly, you would need to give your employer a cause, and in that case - no severance,

Perhaps, depending on your location, even charges

Not to mention, potentially ruined reputation, depending on your industry

Answer (score 2):

You just might discover that "the workplace is a *small town."*  Bosses talk to other bosses at dinner parties.  If you get a reputation – first of all, for being someone that someone had to "fire" – then for being someone who required someone else to do it – well ... ***"word gets around faster than you do."***

You know perfectly well what you should do:  give notice, continue to work at least two more weeks if asked, and thank them for giving you a going-away party.

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely rare that it is a good idea, but it happens. I have seen one or two cases where a truly excellent employee found themselves in a terribly-managed workplace. (In both cases it was through corporate acquisition; the employee likely would not have joined the new company of their own accord.)

Through no real fault of their own, they found themselves in the bad graces of the new management. (And for the record I also knew people in that company's management at that point, so I was able to verify both sides of this story.) They would have quit, but decided to stick it out and see if they would be fired. They were fired, given generous severance, and moved on to a much better job - that they were already interviewing for - a few weeks later.

Let me re-emphasize that these circumstances are extremely rare, and unless you have an excellent reputation and professional network there is significant downside risk.

Comment: There is a big difference between sticking something out to see what happens knowing a termination is likely and actively engaging in behaviors with a design on being terminated.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Agreed, although the question does not explicitly specify that OP intends to actively engage in objectively fireable behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is indeed not impossible to get fired on purpose in order to receive a severance package. [Episode 7 of season 2 of the serie "Better call Saul"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflatable_(Better_Call_Saul)) might serve as inspiration how to pull this off.

However I think in practice it is quite difficult to exactly hit that sweet spot of doing something bad enough that the company wants to get rid of you immediately but not bad enough that you forfeit your right to said severance.

Other considerations not to pull/try a stunt like this would be the desire to maintain your professional reputation or just being a decent person.

Comment: Answers should stand alone without needing information from links (which can change or be removed). Summarise what method was used in the episode.

Answer (score 0):

Getting fired intentionally is never a good idea it might cost you your future job and also you cannot put it as a reference even if put it in your resume they might say bad about you. think about it what if your new employer is somehow connected to your old employer and they might eventually know about your past job which you got yourself fired. Your new employer will come to you and ask you that why did you got fired from your last job and why didn't you told us about it. At that time you cannot say you got yourself fired intentionally because you didn't like that job. that will give them a very bad impression of you. So reconsider it and think about it again before doing it.